# Hibernate Critera Query for One to Many and one to many continous mapping - table or view doesnt exist

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, one-to-many, one-to-one

Need your help.

I am using Hibernate 3.6 with annotations and have 3 tables/classes with mappings.
Class A is mapped with Class B as oneToMany and ClassB is mapped with Class C as OneToOne. I am trying to insert and load the values.

If I directly call .get method of session, it successfully returns the object with all mappings. But when I use criteria or hql to add some condition it gives me an error that ORA-00942: table or view does not exist (Using oracle).

When I call .get method, it doesn't generate any sqls but with Criteria and HQL it generates insert SQLs. I don't understand why Insert queries on fetching the data.

Here are the logs :

```
`Hibernate: insert into A values(???) 
Hibernate: insert into B values(???)
Hibernate: insert into C values(???)
Hibernate: insert into A_B (A_ID, bProperty_ID)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper(line 146): ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`


Class A {
  @Id 
  @Column(name = "A_ID",unique = true, nullable = false)
  int id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //lazy tried
  private Set<B> transactionDetails = new HashSet<B>();
}

Class B {

  @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",parameters =     @Parameter(name = "property", value = "aProperty"))
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
  @Column(name = "B_ID",unique = true, nullable = false)
  int id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID", nullable = false, insertable=false,   updatable=false)
  private  A aProperty;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")
  private C c;
}

Class C {
  @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",parameters =     @Parameter(name = "property", value = "bProperty"))
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
  @Column(name = "C_ID",unique = true, nullable = false)
  int id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private B b;
}
```

Does anybody knows it like why its giving error "table or view doesn't exist" ? when I am using criteria or hql with/without condition.

```
    Criteria crQuery = getSession().createCriteria(A.class);
```

This above line gives the error. where as if I try 
    getSession().get("idFromDB");

No error, runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding annotations to the classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "<your sql table name>")
Class A {
  ...
```